# c++ 20 concepts in derived template class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

for my test about CRTP I created this base class:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    void print() const { std::cout << "print\n"; }
};
```

And this class:

```
struct A: public Base<A>
{
    void printSub() { std::cout << "printSub from A\n"; }
};
```

And I can use these classes without problem:

```
A a1{};
a1.print();
a1.printSub();
```

My problem is: how is possible to use concept/requires for template class?

I want add something like this:

```
template<typename Derived> requires requires (Derived t) {
    t.printSub();
}
struct Base
{
    void print() { std::cout << "print\n"; }
};
```

To accept only **Derived** class with **printSub** method. But I receive this error:

*template constraint failure...*

I did some tests but I did not find solutions (I also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921797/c-concepts-checking-if-derived-from-a-templated-class-with-unknown-template-p) but it can't help me).

Where am I wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: You just can't. `Derived` isn't complete yet, so you can't constraint `Base` on anything in `Derived`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully constrain the derived class template parameters of a CRTP base class for the same reason that you can't do this:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base
{
  using alias = Derived::SomeAlias;
};
```

`Derived` isn't complete yet, and using a constraint usually requires completeness.